# Program against an interface in node.js?

Tags: node.js, dependency-injection

Dependency injection and programming against an interface is standard in C# and Java. I am wondering can this be achieved in Node.js too? For example I am programming a memory cache module and ideally it should expose an interface, let's say with two methods getKey and putKey. I can have one implementation with ioredis and another one with just plain memory cache. But my application will only depend on the memory cache interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript uses Duck Typing

> In computer programming with object-oriented programming languages,
>   duck typing is a style of dynamic typing in which an object's current
>   set of methods and properties determines the valid semantics, rather
>   than its inheritance from a particular class or implementation of a
>   specific interface.

from [Wikipedia - Duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)

This means that you can make a function expect a object as an argument and assume it has some specific functions or properties. i.e:

```
function addAreas(s1, s2){
    //We can't know for sure if s1 or s2 have a getArea() function before the code is executed
    return s1.getArea() + s2.getArea();
}
```

To test if an object have a specific function, we can do the following:

```
function isShape(obj){
    return obj.implements("getArea") && obj.implements("getPerimeter");
}
```

Both can be combined into the following:

```
function addAreas(s1, s2){
    if(isShape(s1) && isShape(s2))
        return s1.getArea() + s2.getArea();

    throw "s1 or s2 are not a shape!"
}
```

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20110316093835/http://blog.michaeleee.com/2008/02/javascript-interfaces-and-duck-typing.html) you can find a great blog post on the subject.

In your example, both your implementations should have a getKey and putKey functions, and the code which expects an object with those functions must test if they were implemented before executing.